# Is there a way to check to see which achievements have been unlocked in unity?

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, game-center

So i'm updating my android and ios application using the unity game engine. I want to add unlockables based on which achievements the user has unlocked. I have about 20 or so achievements. I can't find anywhere a method to check to see if a particular achievement has been unlocked or not. Im using Gamecenter for ios and Google Play Games for android.

Answer (score 2):

The Social class should provide what you need:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Social.html

most particularly https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Social.LoadAchievements.html